# How can I put a ip field with the cidr?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a field in Django Models like this:

```
ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
```

But with this field I can't save the CIDR, How could I do? I should put a new field for the CIDR?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Django has no specific CIDR type for fields: 
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1636
This bug is marked as 'won't fix'.

I believe you can use charfield or make [custom field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-model-fields/) type.